# tvos: How can a view controller detect that the user has selected "Cancel" in a "Sleep / Cancel" screen

Tags: tvos

In "tvos", if the user is watching an app and performs a long press on the "Home" button, then it appears a system screen with two options ("Sleep"/"Cancel"), that is:

Sleep now?
Sleep/Cancel

I would like to know if there is a way to detect, in the view controller of my app, that the button "Cancel" has been selected or, al least, to have the chance to execute some code after coming back from the system screen (with the "Sleep/Cancel" options) if the "Cancel" option has been selected; because under this situation, methods like "viewWillAppear, ..." are not called.

Comment: You can use Javascript for this.

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

In your application delegate class, the method `applicationWillResignActive` should be called when the Sleep/Cancel menu appears.

If the user chose to cancel, you should get a call to the method `applicationDidBecomeActive` when the application get the focus back.

Those are the same events you should get when your application goes in background and foreground (like when you "long press" the MENU button).

Comment: Thanks, I will control it in those methods from "AppDelegate".

Answer (score 1):

I have tried another solution; that is, in the "viewWillAppear" of the "ViewController" I am interesting in, I have added the following notification:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     NSNotificationCenter * nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
     [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
 }

 - (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];  
 }

 - (void) appWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
     //DO YOUR DESIRED ACTION
}
```

In this way, I can detect in that "ViewController" that I come back from a "Cancel" action